# How to show the available drivers?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

```kotlin
override fun onDriverInfoLoadSuccess(driverGeoModel: DriverGeoModel?) {
        //if we already have the marker with this key, don't set it again
        if (!Constants.markerList.containsKey(driverGeoModel?.key)) {
            Constants.markerList[driverGeoModel!!.key!!] = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(driverGeoModel.geoLocation!!.latitude, driverGeoModel.geoLocation!!.longitude))
                .flat(true)
                .title(Constants.buildName(driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel!!.firstName,driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel!!.lastName))
                .snippet(driverGeoModel.driverInfoModel!!.phoneNumber)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_display))
            )!!

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cityName)) {
            val driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Constants.DRIVER_LOCATION_REFERENCE)
                .child(cityName)
                .child(driverGeoModel?.key!!)

            driverLocation.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                        if (Constants.markerList.get(driverGeoModel.key!!) != null) {
                           val marker = Constants.markerList.get(driverGeoModel.key!!)
                           marker?.remove()
                           Constants.markerList.remove(driverGeoModel.key)
                            driverLocation.removeEventListener(this)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Snackbar.make(requireView(), error.message,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            })
        }
    }

    override fun onFirebaseFailed(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

    private fun loadAvailableDrivers() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            return
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Snackbar.make(requireView(), it.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.addOnSuccessListener { location ->

                //load all drivers in this city

                val geoCoder = Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault())
                val addressList: List<Address>?

                try {
                    location?.latitude.let {
                        addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                            it!!,
                            location.longitude,
                            1

                        )
                    }
                    val cityName = addressList?.get(0)!!.locality

                    //Query
                    val driverLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference(Constants.DRIVER_LOCATION_REFERENCE)
                        .child(cityName)
                    val gf = GeoFire(driverLocationRef)
                    val geoQuery = gf.queryAtLocation(
                        GeoLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude),
                        distance
                    )
                    geoQuery.removeAllListeners()

                    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
                        override fun onKeyEntered(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
                            Constants.driversFound?.add(DriverGeoModel(key!!, location!!))
                        }

                        override fun onKeyExited(key: String?) {

                        }

                        override fun onKeyMoved(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {

                        }

                        override fun onGeoQueryReady() {
                            if (distance <= LIMIT_RANGE) {
                                distance++
                                loadAvailableDrivers()
                            } else {
                                distance = 0.0
                                addDriverMarker()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onGeoQueryError(error: DatabaseError?) {
                            Snackbar.make(requireView(), error!!.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                        }

                    })

                    driversLocationRef.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
                        override fun onChildAdded(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?
                        ) {
                            val geoQueryModel = snapshot.getValue(GeoQueryModel::class.java)
                            val geoLocation =
                                GeoLocation(geoQueryModel?.l!![0], geoQueryModel.l!![1])
                            val driverGeoModel = DriverGeoModel(snapshot.key, geoLocation)
                            val newDriverLocation = Location("")
                            newDriverLocation.latitude = geoLocation.latitude
                            newDriverLocation.longitude = geoLocation.longitude
                            val newDistance = location.distanceTo(newDriverLocation) / 1000 // in km
                            if (newDistance <= LIMIT_RANGE) {
                                findDriverByKey(driverGeoModel)
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        override fun onChildChanged(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        override fun onChildMoved(
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            previousChildName: String?
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            Snackbar.make(requireView(), error.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                        }

                    })

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Snackbar.make(requireView(), e.message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

    }
```

Hello,

I have been working on an Android Studio project where I need to load available drivers based on the user's location. Unfortunately, my current implementation doesn't seem to be working as expected, and I'm facing difficulties in resolving the issue.

To provide some context, I have already implemented the following steps:

Permissions: I have checked for and granted the necessary location permissions (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) in my AndroidManifest.xml file. I have also included the appropriate runtime permission checks in my code using checkSelfPermission.

Location Retrieval: I am using the fusedLocationProviderClient to retrieve the user's last known location. The code snippet I provided includes the logic to retrieve the location and handle success and failure scenarios.

Geocoding: After obtaining the user's location, I am using a Geocoder instance to retrieve the address information, specifically the city name. This city name is crucial for querying the available drivers in that particular city.

Querying Drivers: Once I have the city name, I am constructing a query to retrieve the available drivers from the Firebase Realtime Database. I am using the GeoFire library to perform a geospatial query based on the user's location and a predefined distance.

Handling Query Results: I have implemented the necessary listeners and callbacks to handle the results of the geospatial query. The GeoQueryEventListener interface is used to listen for driver entries that fall within the specified distance range. Additionally, I have also implemented a ChildEventListener to listen for changes in the driver's location.

Despite following these steps, I am unable to successfully load the available drivers in my application. I suspect there might be some issues with my implementation, possibly related to the database query or the way I handle the query results.

I am reaching out to the Stack Overflow community for assistance in identifying and resolving the problem. If anyone has experience with loading drivers based on location in Android Studio or can provide guidance on troubleshooting the issue, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Please find the code snippet I shared earlier for reference. If you notice any mistakes or potential areas of improvement, your insights would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!